# Failing to link standard library in OCaml-Java

Tags: ocaml, jvm-languages

I need to convert a simple OCaml file into JAR file so that I can run atop JVM platform.

This OCaml file needs to use the Big_int module. There is this line of code

```
open Big_int
```

But it always returns me this line of error `Error: Reference to undefined global`Big_int'` when I try to run ocamljava to convert it into jar file.

```
ocamljava -o myprog.jar source.ml
```

I am able to see `big_int.cmi`, `big_int.cmj`, `big_int.cmx`, `big_int.mli`, `nums.cma`, `nums.cmja`, etc on this directory `/Users/myname/.opam/ocamljava-2.0-alpha2/lib/ocaml`. I know that the Big_int is residing inside these libraries; but I don't know how to link them into compilation.

By the way, I'm using [OCamlJava 2.0](http://www.ocamljava.org/files/doc/manual/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Erencie,

Entering `open Big_int` only accesses the compiled interface (.cmi file) for `big_int`, but does not load the implementation of `big_int`.

Implementations for user modules can be entered with the `#load` directive.

In your case, you want to do the following:

```
   #load "file-name";;
```

This is going to load in memory a bytecode object file (.cmo file) or library file (.cma file) produced by the batch compiler ocamlc.

Thus you should do the following:

```
   #load "big_int.cmo";;
```

If the object file for big_int does not exist yet, you should compile big_int.ml first.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add the "nums" library to the command-line, as in:

```
ocamljava nums.cmja source.ml
```

Also note that the implementation of "nums" in OCaml-Java has been only
lightly tested, and may contain bugs. If you encounter a bug, it would
be nice to report it at https://github.com/xclerc/ocamljava.